# Two 'self-updating' properties in WPF MVVM

Tags: wpf, architecture, mvvm

Considering you have an MVVM Architecture in WPF like [Josh Smith's examples](http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2008/11/14/using-a-viewmodel-to-provide-meaningful-validation-error-messages/)

How would you implement two properties 'synced' that update eachother? I have a Price property, and a PriceVatInclusive property in my model.

-When the Price changes, I want to see the Vat inclusive price to automatically be 'Price * 1.21'.

-Vice versa, when the PriceVatInclusive changes, I want the Price to be 'PriceVatInclusive / 1.21'

Any ideas on that?

And what if your model is a Entity framework entiry? You can't use the approach above then... no? Should you put calculating code in the ViewMOdel or ... ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way:

```
    public class Sample : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private const double Multiplier = 1.21;
        #region Fields
        private double price;
        private double vat;
        #endregion

        #region Properties
        public double Price
        {
            get { return price; }
            set
            {
                if (price == value) return;
                price = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Price"));
                Vat = Price * Multiplier;
            }
        }

        public double Vat
        {
            get { return vat; }
            set
            {
                if (vat == value) return;
                vat = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Vat"));
                Price = Vat / Multiplier;
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members
        protected void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler ev = PropertyChanged;
            if (ev != null)
            {
                ev(this, e);
            }
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        #endregion
    }
```

If you can derive from DependencyObject, you can use Dependency Properties.

```
public class Sample : DependencyObject
{
    private const double Multiplier = 1.21;

    public static readonly DependencyProperty VatProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Vat", typeof(double), typeof(Sample), 
        new PropertyMetadata(VatPropertyChanged));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty PriceProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Price", typeof(double), typeof(Sample), 
        new PropertyMetadata(PricePropertyChanged));

    private static void VatPropertyChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Sample sample = obj as Sample;
        sample.Price = sample.Vat / Multiplier;
    }

    private static void PricePropertyChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Sample sample = obj as Sample;
        sample.Vat = sample.Price * Multiplier;
    }

    #region Properties
    public double Price
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(PriceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(PriceProperty, value); }
    }

    public double Vat
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(VatProperty); }
        set { SetValue(VatProperty, value); }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Yes ok, But what if your model is a Entity framework entiry? You can't use the approach above then... no? Should you put calculating code in the ViewMOdel or ... ?

Comment: Watch out for Mr. Infinite Loop with the first example!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Polymod.NET](http://polymod.codeplex.com/).
If you have a 'Price' property on a domain object, you can create a model for that domain class, define a formula 'PriceVat' = Price * 0.1. The model will know that PriceVat changes when Price changes, and tell the UI about it.

Your domain class doesn't even have to be INotifyable!